# Using emmet with a react app in vs code is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

In VS Code React emmet is not working even though I have this setting in my `settings.json`  file

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Does anyone have the same problem? Any solution would be perfect.

Comment: Do you have the emmet extension?

Comment: Emmet was working until yesterday but it suddenly stop working this

Comment: Support for Emmet snippets and expansion is built right into Visual Studio Code, no extension required. This is what visual studio docs say

Answer (score 2):

Saw this from a previous thread and it worked for me, but use emmet autocomplete on a normal HTML file (index.HTML) and it should work for your JSX too.

Comment: If you saw this on a previous thread, it might be helpful to link it. Or if already on stack overflow, mark this as duplicate

Comment: Problem is solved when i write something in HTML file but for every project I have to do the same in order to emmet works. I dont understand why it suddenly became like this. And  nobody is complaining about this problem,  is it only me having this issue or what ?

Comment: This worked for me. After I added all the emmet settings, I had to edit a plain html file and select an emmet autocomplete. After that it worked in my react js files fine.

Answer (score 2):

As linked to the github issue by Mark, this is relatively new and not related to other common "Emmet not working" posts. Apparently it's rooted in an  unexpected delay with Emmet recognizing filetypes in a workspace. Manually expanding in an HTML file seems to kicks it back into gear.

For me though, even that wasn't working. I had no issues a week ago but now Emmet was unresponsive regardless of filetype.

I followed [a suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137012#issuecomment-968116557) in the same github thread to also add

```
 "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

And that seemed to work. **Remember to close all open VS code windows.** I had a second window open which I think was also preventing the new setting from applying.

Comment: This worked for me.  It's a checkbox in settings now.
I wasn't able to "div." + TAB to get <div className=""></div>
This fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

You may be seeing this issue: there was a recent regression in emmet functionality, see [Emmet does not work in js/jsx files for VS Code 1.62.2(Universal)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137012)
.

It appears to be fixed in the Insiders Build and should be out in Stable in early December 2021.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem indeed.

> Emmet>including Language>"javascript":"javascriptreact"

was present but I cannot use it in react JSX although it was working in plain HTML. Then I installed an extension called `JSX HTML` Which solved my problem.